# JSON Object to string Swift UI

Tags: json, xcode, swiftui

```
import SwiftUI

extension String{
    func load() ->UIImage {
        
        do{
            //string to URL
            guard let url = URL(string: self) else{
                //empty image if wrong url
                return UIImage()
            }
            //url to data
            let data : Data = try Data(contentsOf: url)
            
            //create uuimage obj from data
            return UIImage(data: data) ?? UIImage()
            
        }catch{
            
            
        }
        return UIImage()
        
    }
}



struct ContentView: View {
    @State private var quoteData : QuoteData?
    
        
    var body: some View {
       
        ZStack{
            VStack{

                
                Text(quoteData?.lat ?? "Latitude")
                Text(quoteData?.long ?? "Longitude")
                

                //------------------------HELP HERE
                Image(uiImage: "https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/staticmap?center=LATITUDE,LONGITUDE&zoom=16&size=400x400&key=AIzaSyClGOTMpV2kKF27bxAo6nm3pIq7zmW69Fw".load())

                
struct QuoteData: Decodable{
    
    //var id: Int
    var long: String
    var lat: String
    var apiURL: String

}
```

I want to insert the long and lat variables of QuoteData inside the url string that is used in IMAGE(uimage

I cant find an answer , been looking for hours with no luck

this is just a fragment of the code it will be nice if someone can help me .

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try something like this, using `\(lat),\(lon)` "...to insert the long and lat variables of QuoteData inside the url string...":

```
struct ContentView: View {

    @State private var quoteData: QuoteData? = QuoteData(long: "139.7514", lat: "35.685", apiURL: "") // for testing, Tokyo
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack{
            Text(quoteData?.lat ?? "Latitude")
            Text(quoteData?.long ?? "Longitude")
            
            if let lat = quoteData?.lat, let lon = quoteData?.long {
                Image(uiImage: "https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/staticmap?center=\(lat),\(lon)&zoom=16&size=400x400&key=AIzaSyClGOTMpV2kKF27bxAo6nm3pIq7zmW69Fw".load())
            }
        }
    }
}
```

PS: this has nothing to do with JSON object to String